# $\lim_{n\to +\infty} |(2n\pi+1/n) \sin(2n\pi+1/n)|$, $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

$\lim_{n\to +\infty} |(2n\pi+1/n) \sin(2n\pi+1/n)|$, $n\in \mathbb N$. I tried L'Hospital which gives
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left| \frac{\sin(2n\pi+1/n)}{(2n\pi+1/n)^{-1}} \right| = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left| \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi x^2+1}{x})(2\pi x^2+1)^2}{x^2} \right|.$$

Is the limit $+\infty$? I am not sure because of the cosine term.

Comment: When can you use the rule of L'Hospital?

Comment: @babemcnuggets $|(2n\pi+1/n) \sin(2n\pi+1/n)|$ is an indeterminate product $0 * \infty$, so I change it to $\frac{0}{0}$ and use L'Hospital.

Comment: I only remember using L'Hospital for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and $\frac{0}{0}$, I might be wrong..

Comment: @babemcnuggets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms

Comment: I deleted my comment I was wrong @user398843

Comment: I was wrong, I deleted the comment.

Comment: It seems everybody is assuming $n$ are only integers, even though this is not stated. If so, is this because of using $n$ instead of $x$, $y$ or some other variable, the nature of the $sin$ expression, or something else? Nonetheless, should this not be explicitly mentioned? If $n$ were to mean the real numbers instead, then there would be no limit as the values would range between $0$ and $2n\pi + \frac{1}{n}$, for various $n$ where $\left\vert \sin\left(2n\pi + \frac{1}{n}\right) \right\rvert = 1$, an infinite # of times.

Comment: Actually, I realized to use l'Hôpital's rule, you need to use the derivative, so would it not assume that $n$ is a real variable? As the OP states trying to use l'Hôpital's rule, it seems this might be the case. If so, then the answer is not $2\pi$ when using just natural numbers, but indeterminate instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry for the confusion, I should had stated that $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @user398843 Thanks for the clarifications. Also, as I stated, note you should not try to use l'Hôpital's rule in that case. You might get the correct answer, but it's not guaranteed. Regarding your question title & text change, note that an easier way to state $n$ is a positive integer is that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., is a natural number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sin$ has period $2\pi$, so $\sin(2n\pi+\frac 1 n)=\sin(\frac 1 n)$. $\lim (|2n\pi+\frac 1 n)\sin(\frac 1 n)|=\lim (|2n\pi+\frac 1 n)(\frac 1 n)|=2\pi$. I have used the fact that $\frac {\sin\, x } x \to 1$ as $ x \to 0$.

Comment: Can we really take the limit sign into the absolute value sign? If $a_n = (-1)^n$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} |(-1)^n| = 1$ but $|\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n|$ does not exist. I asked this because you use $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: @user398843 When $\lim a_n$ exists we can take the limit inside. In our case the limit exists.